How do I configure Co-DETR to predict quadrilaterals instead of bounding boxes?
I've trained a Co-DETR model with the MMDetection framework on a COCO dataset for handwritten census records where the annotations are quadrilaterals that are nearly rectangular but not exactly due to perspective shifts or rotations.
The model trains well, but when I run inference, the model outputs bounding boxes instead of the quadrilaterals. This is problematic when the census records are either rotated or perspective shifted, as shown for this green column:

As can be seen here, the top left corner of the column and the green bounding box match as well as the bottom right corner and the bounding box are pretty close, but the other corners of the column have diverged from the corners of the predicted bounding box because the image here is slightly rotated.
Are there any settings for this framework that make it so that the model can output quadrilateral predictions (essentially 4 key points per class) that match the annotations it was trained on instead of bounding boxes?
